# Pulling questions based on category & user

Tags: php, database, mysqli, web

So I am developing a website that has questions across different categories, but depending on the user the question will be different.

an example : Team A has access to questions (Cat 1 - Question 1, Cat 2 - question 2, cat 3, question 3, and cat4 - question 4), and then team B has access to question (cat 1 - question 5, cat 2 - question 6, cat 4 - question 7)....

So each team will have these 4 categories but the question for the users may be different depending on the team ID.
http://puu.sh/ilYss/2c93f9a0d5.png

So I need to pull the question based on the category along with also based on the team and I don't know how to go about linking the button so when team A click the Web 'View Question' button it displays their questions and team B a different question.

Here is my database structure : http://puu.sh/im1D1/caa9c27015.pdf

So Far I have the following :

```
$order = "SELECT * FROM questionscat  ORDER BY questionCatID";
```

Challenge.php

```
<div class="row">
                <?php
while($data = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
    if($data[0] != null){
  echo('
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
                              <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                              <i class="fa fa-question fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <h4>'.$data[1].'</h4>
                        <p>'.$data[2].'</p>
                        <a href="question.php?id='.$data[0].'" class="btn btn-primary">View Question </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
  ');}else{
        echo "Hello";
    }
        }

        ?>


        </div>
```

I have tried multiple queries but cannot get it right  (example)

```
SELECT q.question,t.questionGroupID,qc.questionCatName FROM questions AS q 
INNER JOIN 
questionscat AS qc 
ON q.questionCatID=qc.questionCatID 
INNER JOIN 
team AS t ON t.questionGroupID=qc.questionCatID WHERE 
qc.questionCatID=2
```

So If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated! or just put me in the right direction

Regards
Syn

Comment: Echoing HTML is **bad** idea !

Comment: Alaias such as `questionscat as qa` does not make any sense. It is hard to read and difficult to analyze. `qc` would be better.

Comment: Ok, Any other recommendations on how I should approach it?

Comment: Yes , 1) Your Pdf file(http://puu.sh/im1D1/caa9c27015.pdf) spans over 10 Pages. Either shorten it or post small Pic here on stackoverflow as image. 2) SQL keywords should be in CAPS case so you can recognize it properly, I edited it.

Comment: The PDF is 8 pages, and I thought rather than pasting tables in here it would be easier to read, sorry! But I need help with a solution to my problem.... so any suggestions on how I could resolve my problem?

Comment: If you dont Edit the question and make clear what you want to achieve , people wont be able to understand it and wont be able to answer. I see noone understood your question properly so noone could answer. Please consider editing question and make it clear.

Comment: I don't think the question is that difficult, and its quiet clear if you see what I;m trying to do... There are 4 categories, users will see all 4 categories but when they click view question their question is different based on the user, So you click on category called 'coding', and you see a question about what is the correct way to write a comment, where as when I click the category its showing me a question about SQL.

Comment: Ok so you mean all see one category Coding , but Team A see other Questions than Team B?

Comment: Yes indeed, How do I link the button to do this?

Comment: Answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

See you want Team A to see Other questions when clicked on Category say `Coding`. And Team B see Different questions when clicked on Same `Coding` category.

So in order to achieve that , you have to Put User Type in `Session` variable which will hold User type say "PHP_Developer" or "SQL_DBA" etc when user logs in.

Now you have User type of logged in user.

Now when I click Link of category say `Coding`, I goto page with that category Id/name , like `abc.com/showquestions.php?category=1` Or `abc.com/showquestions.php?categoryName=Coding`.

Now on this page you get category Id Or name which you can use in `WHERE clause` of sql query. Now you want 2nd parameter as well so that you can filter Category question for `That` group of users. So use here session variable which we stored while login , so you get 2nd condition in `WHERE clause` like `WHERE category = 1 AND userType='".$_SESSION['userType']."'`.

Hope it makes sense.

**Edit : Even more simplified**

```
SELECT q.question,t.questionGroupID,qc.questionCatName FROM questions AS q 
INNER JOIN 
questionscat AS qc 
ON q.questionCatID=qc.questionCatID 
INNER JOIN 
team AS t ON t.questionGroupID=qc.questionCatID WHERE 
qc.questionCatID=2
AND t.questionGroupID = '".$_SESSION['userType']."'
```

Comment: Hi JQuery, Sorry for the delay in getting back to you, So my plan for this event is to have a single team login (not individual Users) so our login system is based on the team's table, I'm not a very experience web developer hence all these questions, But how would it work is the userType for both teams were 'Member'? Also when I run the query in PhpMyAdmin, It shows all the questions back belong to one category rather than one from each category? Am I misunderstanding it?

Comment: Let me try Explain what I am doing, I have different categories of questions (Web, Trivia..) and we have multiple teams, on day 1, we want team A and B to be able to see questions that are for round 1 session 1, on Day 2, we want team C and D to be able to see questions from round 1 session 2.
So to do this I have created question Groups (Round 1 session 1 = questionGroup1), I  then assign Team A and B question Group 1, and then Team C and D question group 2, Etc…

Comment: which displays their questions and then I can update the team A and B with the new questionGroupID to display the questions for that round.
 
I need help coding that page so it displays the correct question to the correct teams.